# Read in a file for word search game C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, ifstream

I am attempting read in a file and create a 2D vector to store the game board for a word search game but I can't seem to get it to read more than the first line.  I'm sure it is something small but I put in a test display for the 'board' vector and all that shows up is the first line of the text file.

Here is some of my code:

'Board.cpp'

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Board::Board(void)
: rows(0)
{
}


Board::~Board(void)
{
}

void Board::readInFile(void)
{
    ifstream indata;
    indata.open("Puzzle.txt");
    indata >> rows;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        char tmpChar;
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            indata >> tmpChar;
            row.push_back(tmpChar);
        }
        board.push_back(row);
    }
    indata.close();
}
```

'Board.h'

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Board
{
public:
    Board(void);
    ~Board(void);
    void readInFile(void);
protected:
    vector<vector<char>> board;
    vector<char>row;    
protected:
    int rows;
};
```

Here is how the text file is set up:

16

BDXWASEESPHWEBGB

SIGJVAWDFLCTZIAM

ENKVESMARNAEBRRI

IKOEOPZLUKMVJDDL

KLIRELOBSNPOFWEC

SBOHKLLRHSIFPANA

RSKWMEEEPEITPTPE

EZPIELLLYMOOQCDH

TAWDLGGLZBUNDHOJ

ASIOJNFOPKAJAPBP

WLRCIILROZXLSCID

SKATEBOARDGCLCIA

LLABESABIVOTNVVE

VOFRISBEETMIEVZG

BWADEVAUCYCSWING

XNJFJPZHBTBFTSAW

Comment: Why do you have a nested for loop? You are reading in one character at a time.  Go read this - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: I guess you need to empty row once you board.push_back(row);

Comment: You don't clear `row` after you append it to `rows` and you don't account for newline characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much better ways to handle input files. Firstly, rather than using a `vector<char>`, just use a `std::string`, and rather than using a `vector<vector<char> >`, just use a `vector<string>`. I'm not sure I understand why `row` is a member of the class if it is only being used to fill the `board`. Anytime you need the last item in board you can just do `board.back()` or `*board.rbegin()`.

```
void Board::readInFile(void)
{
    ifstream indata("Puzzle.txt", ios::in);
    if(!ifstream.is_open())
        return;
    indata >> rows;    //you don't really need to do this if you take 
                         //the row count out of the file, but if you can't 
                         //change the file, leave it in so as not to corrupt 
                         //the loop that follows
    string line;
    while(getline(indata, line)){
        board.push_back(line);
    }
    indata.close();
}
```

Really, you don't need to have the file store the `rows` variable.

---

Your function would also be more reusable if readInFile took the filename as a parameter so it could open anything instead of only one specific filename.

Comment: The main reason I have it set up the way I do is right after the letters in the text file is the list of words that I need to take in and search for. So I'm guessing while() would take in more than I need to just setting up the word search.

Comment: Ah, your question didn't specify that. In that case you could move the `getline()` inside the loop that iterates based on the `rows` number. Alternatively, you could have a break-character in the file after the letters and then `break` from the loop if the line contains only that break-character (and, likely, a newline).

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't mention that. Can I use 'string line;' if the board vector is 'vector<vector<char>> board;'.  This is an assignment for class and I assume he is telling us to use 'char' for the purpose of making it easy to search individual letters to match it to the word.

Comment: No, I don't think the assignment operator is defined for `vector<char> = string`. I don't understand why he would tell you to use char. It is not difficult to search the individual letters of a string. See this documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Or this tutorial here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html

Comment: That is what I thought too. For the purpose of this final assignment, if I use string instead of char to get this to work and he marks me down I'm not to worried.  I implemented your suggested and seems to be working well now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would but being so new to the site I still need 15 rep to be able to upvote. :( When I get 15 I'll make sure to throw one your way. Very helpful!

Comment: Don't `close` a local `fstream`. It will be closed by the destructor (RAII). And it would be even more reusable if an `istream&` were passed as a parameter, leaving the concrete type of the stream to the choice of the caller.